# Version number as a variable in a shell script

Tags: shell, yaml, concourse

I’m using a semver resource where the version number is stored in git. Now I want to use the version number in the filename of the build file that is stored in a S3 bucket. We have the pipeline pointing to a separate task-file which points to a shell script. It is in that shell script that I want to use the version as a variable. Now in the shell file the version variable is replaced by the literal argument text [version/number] instead of with the actual version number.

How would I use the version number from the resource in this case?

Comment: Show us the relevant shell script code.

Comment: Well I want to use a version number like so: tar -cf ../filename-${1}.tar

Answer (score 2):

The version number will be stored in a file called `<version-resource-name>/version` in the task container, so to access the version number you will want to `cat` that file.

For example, if have a job that gets a version resource.

```
get: my-version
```

I can access the version number in my `task.sh` with:

```
VERSION="$(cat my-version/version)"
```

Comment: Oh and I got the same answer here as well: https://github.com/concourse/semver-resource/issues/48